# How to implement this bitwise manipulation?

Tags: c++, logic, bit-manipulation

I have an integral type with some value. E.g. say some `int foo` has the bit representation:

11011001101101011010101000001111

I need a function `f` that manipulates it as follows: Prepending a 0 makes it

011011001101101011010101000001111 (*)

To obtain the final value I need, the following bit sequence is made, which has ones whenever successive bits of (*) are unequal.

10110101011011110111111100001000

which is `f(foo)`

How should this be implemented in c++?

Comment: i dont understand? a big enough container set to the first value will already have prepended zeros?

Comment: @erip Why not? It does...

Comment: Do you mean delta coding?

Comment: i count 32 bits am i being blind to something or are you prohibited to use 64 bit integers?

Comment: @deviantfan ugh I need coffee... comment removed.

Comment: @Neijwiert `int foo` is 32 bit. So is `f(foo)`. What `f` does is this: Look at `foo` and check at which positions the binary representation change between 0 and 1. Those are the positions of the binary representation of `f(foo)` that need be 1. The first bit of `foo` is considered "changed" if it is 1, which is why I added the 0

Comment: What really confused me was the "prepending a 0", when you apparently mean "shift bits one position to right". If you were to prepend a 0, the number would have 1 more bit than previously, but have exactly the same value, so that all bits in same position would still be the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short: solution is

```
unsigned f(unsigned x)
{
  return x ^ (x >> 1U);
}
```

Brief explanation:

You need to bitwise compare some numbers, having `1` if the bits differ, and `0` otherwise. That's exactly what the `^` operation does.

Further, you need to compare `i`-th bit of the number with `(i+1)`-st (and `31`-st bit with `0`), but `^` compares `i`-th bits of some numbers. So, we should transform the number in such a way that it will have bit from `(i+1)`-st place on `i`-th place, and add `0` in the very beginning. That's what exactly `>>` operation does.

Also, please mention that

```
int f(int x)
{
  return x ^ (x >> 1);
}
```

will not work correctly for all cases, since negative `int` numbers (all numbers starting with `1`), will get `1` at the beginning when being shifted right.

Comment: KISS. +1 Was typing this up -- you beat me by seconds. :)

Comment: Lol ... I knew I was forgetting something :D